# This .asp file need some dll that my windows server 2003 64bits dont have

Tags: dll, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

When i try to run these .asp code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx1hNT8CEtf6cUFjYlJia2JBUGM/edit?usp=sharing

i have the following error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx1hNT8CEtf6dno3ajBpanl2OXc/edit?usp=sharing

The site is running on a Windows server 2003 64 bits, i have done a search on internet and look like is some dll missing, can i discovery what dll just with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a classic ASP file, not an ASP.NET file.  Line 99 has this line of code:

```
Set objCrip = Server.CreateObject("Criptografia.Cripto")
```

`Criptografia` is usually the name of the DLL and `Cripto` is the name of the object inside of it.  You can perform a search on your hard drive for `Criptografia` to see if it exists or search your Registry for the full name `Criptografia.Cripto` to see if there is a different DLL associated with it.